# Detect if cors is enabled?

Tags: javascript, cors

How do i go about detecting if cors is enabled on a html5 audio element's remote file through javascript?

I would like to output a visualizer attached to the AudioContext only IF the audio tag's remote src file has cors enabled.

Comment: I don't see any reason to specifically detect CORS. Just try to access the resource, if it fails, don't show your visualiser.

Comment: yeah you not seeing it doesn't mean I don't need it...

Comment: But what do you need it for? How is disabled CORS any different from a mundane networking error?

Comment: Well I was trying to help. And if you had realised that you didn't need it, that would surely have solved your problem.

Comment: :D no problem thank you for the attempt at help! I do need it though :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just request the file through javascript before loading the resource, and check the response headers for the **access-control-allow-origin** header.

If the resource has the header, update the  tag's src attribute with the resources' URL.

jQuery example of checking headers from request:

```
var audioSource = 'mysite.com/audiosource.ogg';
$.get( audioSource, function( data, textStatus, request) {
    var header = request.getResponseHeader('access-control-allow-origin');

    if(typeof header !== 'undefined') {
         $('#audiotag').attr('src', audioSource);
    }
});
```

It's worth noting that *if* the access-control-allow-origin header is set and you're not requesting from the right domain you'll be forbidden from loading the resource anyway

Comment: yeah technically thats not true you can load a audio file into a audio element through JS you just can't get at the conteext.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't get at the AudioContext?

Comment: getResponseHeader will not return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value unless the server also responds with a `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header listing it as one of the exposed headers

Comment: @glcheetham: i see `access-control-allow-origin` header in chrome but not in IE for same resource.